# Recursion explanation

Tags: c, recursion

I was trying a random program to practice recursion.

I am unable to figure out what is happening

```
int fun(int *list,int l,int h)
{
    if(l==h)
        return list[l];
    int b = fun(list,l+1,h)+ fun(list,l,h-1);
    printf("%d \n",b);
    return b;
}

void main()
{
    int ar[]= { 1,2,3,4};
    fun(ar,0,3);
}
```

Could someone draw recursion tree maybe? Also what is the value of b at each point? Thanks!

Comment: try running the program and using your debugger.

Comment: Note that values of `b` will be undefined since `fun` doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: Did you get no warning from your compiler that `fun` doesn't return an `int`?

Comment: Ahh recursion. That mind blower of a computer science concept. I understand exactly where you are and I've been right there. Visualize recursion like a bunch of boxes, where each box is a call to your function. So as you come into the function, that's the first box. Then, as your base condition is not met, add another box to the right (representing another call to the function). Keep adding boxes.. keep moving to the right. When your condition is finally met, unwind those boxes, starting from where you are, going all the way back to the left. That will give you a starting point.

Comment: @user3308043 Why does that sound more complicated? I seem to have extra boxes now. What do I do with them? WHAT?

Comment: With python i do get a error after printing 7 and 5 but with c i get no warning/error! C gives an output 7 5 6 5 3 6 6

Comment: @FunctionR Each box represents each call to your function. When that base condition is not met (if l==h), another call to the function will be made. So the first call to your function, as in, when you start the recursive process, is your first box. Condition isn't met? Add a connected box on the right side. Again, condition isn't met? Add another. Keep adding a boxes until your condition is finally met (l==h). Then, unwind. Go left one box, go left one box, etc, until you're finally at the original box, which is when your recursive call will end.

Comment: Fwiw, you don't the list ptr *and* two index. The list ptr can act as one of the index params itself via ptr-math. [See it live](http://ideone.com/pDE3e8).

Comment: @FunctionR I'm commenting on the general concept of recursion. Once you're able to visualize what's happening, you will have an easier understanding of recursion in all cases. Each box resides on 'the stack'. The stack unwinds after your recursive condition is met. When you add too many boxes (too many recursive calls) the stack can overflow. Hence the name of this website.

Comment: @WhozCraig point noted! Could you explain step by step the recursion for your code?

Comment: @user3308043 I know what you are doing, I just found it a bit over-complicated, but to each his own. One thing though, it is true a the stack can overflow from too much recursion. However, recursion is not the only way a stack can overflow. One way to improve recursion is to do tail recursion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

Comment: @FunctionR From wikipedia: "The other major cause of a stack overflow results from an attempt to allocate more memory on the stack than will fit, for example by creating local array variables that are too large. For this reason some authors recommend that arrays larger than a few kilobytes should be allocated dynamically instead of as a local variable.". So to directly answer your question, yes.

Comment: @Dubby you have several very nice examples below that do so already. I just wanted to mention one of the parameters was not needed. That ptr-math-splitting, btw, is incredibly handy when writing recursive partitioning algorithms for things like sorting algorithms.

Comment: @FunctionR http://caseelse.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/recursionagain.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slight retool of your app will likely tell you exactly what you want to see. Modifying your algorithm to include a depth-parameter and some creative lead-space printing with an argument-specified left-justificaction gives us this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fun(int *list, int l, int h, int d)
{
    printf("%*sfunc(list, %d, %d)\n", d, "", l, h);
    int b = (l==h) ? list[l] : fun(list, l+1, h, d+2)+ fun(list, l, h-1, d+2);
    printf("%*sresult: %d \n", d, "", b);
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int ar[]= { 1,2,3,4};
    fun(ar, 0, 3, 0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The results somewhat speak for themselves:

**Output**

```
func(list, 0, 3)
  func(list, 1, 3)
    func(list, 2, 3)
      func(list, 3, 3)
      result: 4 
      func(list, 2, 2)
      result: 3 
    result: 7 
    func(list, 1, 2)
      func(list, 2, 2)
      result: 3 
      func(list, 1, 1)
      result: 2 
    result: 5 
  result: 12 
  func(list, 0, 2)
    func(list, 1, 2)
      func(list, 2, 2)
      result: 3 
      func(list, 1, 1)
      result: 2 
    result: 5 
    func(list, 0, 1)
      func(list, 1, 1)
      result: 2 
      func(list, 0, 0)
      result: 1 
    result: 3 
  result: 8 
result: 20
```

With a few modifications (not shown here; left as an exercise for the reader), you can draw the terminal-dependent line art chars to amplify even more the "what called what and returned what?" question. The following was the output of such a mod using VT100 compliant escape sequences (which SO thankfully consumes nicely in their formatting). Enjoy!

```
┌func(list, 0, 3)
│ ┌func(list, 1, 3)
│ │ ┌func(list, 2, 3)
│ │ │ ┌func(list, 3, 3)
│ │ │ └result: 4
│ │ │ ┌func(list, 2, 2)
│ │ │ └result: 3
│ │ └result: 7
│ │ ┌func(list, 1, 2)
│ │ │ ┌func(list, 2, 2)
│ │ │ └result: 3
│ │ │ ┌func(list, 1, 1)
│ │ │ └result: 2
│ │ └result: 5
│ └result: 12
│ ┌func(list, 0, 2)
│ │ ┌func(list, 1, 2)
│ │ │ ┌func(list, 2, 2)
│ │ │ └result: 3
│ │ │ ┌func(list, 1, 1)
│ │ │ └result: 2
│ │ └result: 5
│ │ ┌func(list, 0, 1)
│ │ │ ┌func(list, 1, 1)
│ │ │ └result: 2
│ │ │ ┌func(list, 0, 0)
│ │ │ └result: 1
│ │ └result: 3
│ └result: 8
└result: 20
```

Comment: Hadn't seen this clever usage of `"%*s"`. Nice :)

Comment: @RSahu I've done it so many times in recursive algorithms I actually *start* writing them with this already in place just to sanity-check the call stack. Btw, if single threaded you can avoid the parameter and use a local-static, doing the same thing ([see it live](http://ideone.com/FI1x0N)). I just chose not to for this example. Glad you liked it.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it should be something like this (not very tree-ish though, just didn't know how else to draw it):

```
fun(ar, 0, 3) -> { (prints 20)
    fun(ar, 1, 3) -> { (prints 12)
        fun(ar, 2, 3) -> { (prints 7)
            fun(ar, 3, 3) + fun(ar, 2, 2)
        } + fun(ar, 1, 2) -> { (prints 5)
            fun(ar, 2, 2) + fun(ar, 1, 1)
    } + fun(ar, 0, 2) -> { (prints 8)
            fun(ar, 1, 2) -> { (prints 5)
                fun(ar, 2, 2) + fun(ar, 1, 1)
            } + fun(ar, 0, 1) -> { (prints 3)
                fun(ar, 1, 1) + fun(ar, 0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you also emit the output at each point? value of b maybe?

Comment: Actually I can't :-). See the comment of simonc above. However I suppose I could do it assuming you return b in your function.

Answer (score 3):

```
1    fun(list,0,3)
2    = fun(list,1,3) + fun(list,0,2)
3    = fun(list,2,3) + fun(list,1,2) + fun(list,1,2) + fun(list,0,1)
4    = fun(list,2,2) + fun(list,3,3) + fun(list,1,1) + fun(list,2,2) + fun(list,1,1) + fun(list,2,2) + fun(list,0,0) + fun(list,1,1)
```

4th line does not have any printf statements.

3rd line will print

```
7
5
5
3
```

2nd line will print

```
12
8
```

1st line will print

```
20
```

Comment: could you specify the line numbers explicitly in the answer?

Comment: Line numbers added. :)